# android: how to add a button with text inside collapsing toolbar

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout

How to achieve the following layout. I could achieve without the add button. But how to add the ADD buttom and add button should disappear along with parallax of the image when scrolled up.

What i found is floating action buttons dont have facility to add text. I have to use button only.

[image]

My xml layout without the add button:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layoutplace1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/framelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"

            app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
            app:layout_collapseMode="none">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="#ffffff"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:theme="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="#574ec1"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="2dp"
                app:tabMode="scrollable"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="#574ec1"
                app:tabTextColor="#8A000000" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="56dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_viewplace1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        app:itemTextColor="#8A000000"
        app:itemIconTint="#8A000000"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Also the text: "UDUPI SRIKRISHNA TEMPLE" which appears in double lines. is that possible.

I add title using

```
collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Udupi Sri krishna Temple");
```

But the title shows only partially and shows ...

Instead i want it to be shown in multiple lines. is it possible

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add button and image like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom|end"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

in your main scrollable content put this code

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: checking looks closer to what i want. Also can you tell how to get the text properly

Comment: text property of what? do you want textview also with button?

Comment: Yes. how to get the entire thing "UDUPI SRI KRISHNA TEMPLE" and the button.

Comment: i added a textview inside the linear layout and got it. thank you

Comment: I have one doubt. If i have a toolbar icon on the right, then the button overlaps on it. Is it possible to vanish the button when i scroll up.

Comment: no it want...because when you scroll your toolbar will collpased...check this out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html

Comment: i am glade to help you

Comment: i have  put recycler view and floating action button but floating action button is not hiding

Answer (score 0):

You can add `TextView`, `Button` or any thing that you want to show on collapsible Layout.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dip"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="20dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

  <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" >

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                     app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
                <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        >
                        <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title_text"
                                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            />
                            <Button
                           android:id="@+id/btntest"
                           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        ... />

                         .......
                 </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
   </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
```

Comment: I tried it. The text and button are added in the top height (?attr/actionBarSize) only. they are not added like the image shown

Comment: i suggest instead of adding inside toolbar add it outside and within collapsingtoolbarlayout

Answer (score 0):

In order to add back button (or any other button or image), you can add it to the Toolbar. If you would like to make this button shown always, whether toolbar is collapsed or not, you can add this line to the toolbar:

```
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
```

If you want the button to disappear when toolbar collapses, replace this line with:

```
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
```

Then you can find this button/image by id from the activity/fragment and add listener to it. The full code for the Toolbar:

```
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:contentScrim="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:src="@drawable/tech"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_back_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_back_arrow_left"/>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```