# requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout 2

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a collapsing toolbar layout which contains some textviews and on collapse shows the toolbar containg a textview. It works perfectly as i wanted but shows an error log  generated repeatedly whenever I collapse the toolbar.

**Layout:**

```
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="center"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="false">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/_15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/a"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="a"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/arates"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="arates"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/aimg"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/bitupcolor"/>
                    </LinearLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/b"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="B"
                        android:textColor="@color/white" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/brates"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text=brates"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bimg"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/_5dp"
                            android:textColor="@color/bitdowncolor"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/btntoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/_30dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/llcollapsing"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:clickable="true">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/btn"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:text="dscbckbsZ"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/_12dp"
                        android:visibility="gone" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/down"
                        android:layout_width="@dimen/_12dp"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/_12dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:background="@mipmap/ic_down"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

**Java Function**

```
    private void dynamicAppbar() {
    appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
        boolean isShow = false;
        int scrollRange = -1;

        @Override
        public void onOffsetChanged(final AppBarLayout appBarLayout, final int verticalOffset) {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (scrollRange == -1) {
                        scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                    }
                    if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                        live_btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        live_btn.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.live_price));
                        separator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        down.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        initListener();
                        isShow = true;
                    } else if (isShow) {
                        separator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        live_btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        down.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        isShow = false;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**error**

```
 requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout{23967ac8 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-720,190 #7f0c0078 app:id/collapsing_toolbar} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{3f2b6761 V.ED..C. ........ 254,0-434,33 #7f0c008a app:id/btn} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout{23967ac8 V.ED.... ........ 0,0-720,190 #7f0c0078 app:id/collapsing_toolbar} during second layout pass: posting in next frame
requestLayout() improperly called by android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [requestLayout() improperly called by CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38913215/requestlayout-improperly-called-by-collapsingtoolbarlayout)

Comment: can u help me how to solve it

Comment: try like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34176722/android-how-to-add-a-button-with-text-inside-collapsing-toolbar